# Jquery spinner initial value not getting set

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spinner

I am using JQuery spinner control on my web form. But it's initial value is not getting set. I am using IE9 + VS2010

Here is the code I have written in my common function. I call this function at run time and send parameters accordingly.

```
function(spinnerid, minval, maxval, initvalue, step) {
$("#" + spinnerid).spinner({ min: minval, max: maxval, increment: step, value: initvalue });
}
```

These are the libraries I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

And this is the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="income" class="income" />
```

Comment: edited my post with corrections

Comment: You've got step and increment the wrong way round.  The option is step, not increment.

Comment: @Archer - oh.. is that the reason for value not getting set, as this is considered as syntax error?

Comment: That would be my first guess, yes.  It may be stopping at the options because on of them is incorrect.  To test, just remove it and see if it sets the value.

Comment: @Archer: No, its not affecting the result

Comment: @Archer From the API documentation these are the correct options [incremental](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#option-incremental) and [step](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#option-step)

Comment: Okay - at least that won't be the next question you ask ;)

Comment: @chridam He's trying to set the step value, but using increment instead - nothing to do with the incremental option.

Comment: Consider removing the "`increment`" option and set your `step` option like `$("#" + spinnerid).spinner( "option", "step", step );`

Comment: Let's not deviate from original problem. My objective is not to set the "step". Now I have totally removed step / increment option. I want to sent the initial value of the slider which is not getting set.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know why the value option isn't working as documented.  I've tried it myself and have the same problem.  This will solve your issue though...

```
function setSpinner(spinnerid, minval, maxval, initvalue) {
    $("#" + spinnerid).spinner({ min: minval, max: maxval }).val(initvalue);
}
```

I just added the `val()` at the end to set the initial value.  (I also added a function name, just because you missed it in your question.  Call it what you need.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no `value` option during `spinner` construction. You will have to use `.val()` just like @Archer suggested.
Also, another issue is `increment`, you mean `incremental`. Or `step` if you're trying to pass in a number. Check the linked documentation.

So your function becomes

```
function(spinnerId, min, max, init, step) {
    $('#' + spinnerId)
        .spinner({min:min, max:max, incremental /*or 'step'?*/:step})
        .val(init)
    ;
}
```

ref:
[spinner API](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#options)

Comment: @Archer 's answer should be accepted. I can't upvote or edit in the extra details I've included in my answer (that's why I wrote my own)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are confusing [jQueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/) with [jQuery EasyUI](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/spinner.php)?
Your call to `.spinner()` is exactly like easyUI's...
<sub>See my other answer for proper usage of jQueryUI</sub>

Answer (score -1):

use also jquery default library...
http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Can you pleas elaborate which library should I include and how it is related to this problem?

Comment: For use jquery you shoul have the main library...
download version 1.8.2 from the link , put the js file in your project folder , and add its ref like the ref to the jquery-ui js file...